# @{Controller.action()} usage in javascript files

Tags: jquery, playframework

I'm building a webapp with jQuery, which is using many $.get(..) and $.post(..) action-calls to my Play Controllers.

Example:

```
$.get('@{Patients.activeEpisodes()}', function(data) {
      $('#secondary').append(data);
});
```

When I create a javascript function directly in my template file, the @{Controller.action()} tags are correctly replaced with the correct url.

But when i put the same function inside a seperate .js file which is imported in the template using the #{script 'myJavaScriptFile.js' /} tag, these @{xxx} tags are not repalced with the correct Url's.

Is there a way to have these tags properly replaced by the templating enginge?
Thanks for your answer!
Richard

Answer (score 0, accepted):

No, the templating engine will only work with the Play Templates. External *.js files are ignored as they are considered to be Javascript files which require no processing.

The only solution is to put that code in the template (or hardcode the path)

Comment: Hmm ok thanks for your answer. Hard coding the url's wont really help the maintainability of the code; i really like the routes config file. An alternative i'm thinking of right now is to put the javascript in a template file dedicated to that script and include the main template.

Comment: @Bjarne77 yes, hardcoding is not an option usually. Putting them on a  template may work, but are you sure you can't just add them to the template that uses the code? It seems quite specific to one page.

Comment: @Peter Villega - I want to bundle all my methods into a few external .js files as they contain complex functionality. 

I've found a workarond by including my .js file in the template like so:
     
         <script>
              #{include '/public/javascripts/myJavascriptFile.js' /}
         </script>

Could it be an extension of the 'include' functionality to allow for .js files to be included (e.g. automatic <script> tags surrounding the code). I think it would make the use of the @{Controller.action()} functionality in combination with the routes file even easier.

Comment: .. or of course let the #{script 'myJavascriptFile.js' /} check for @{Controller.action()} fields..